# Passive voice with must or have to

Tags: modal-verbs, syntax, passive-voice

I have the sentence.

> Criteria are initialized a default value

I would like to improve the sentence.

> Criteria must are initialized a default value

Can I write this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. When you use a modal auxiliary verb like **must**, the verb that follows it is in the infinitive (the bare form, without "to"). You *can* write

> Criteria **must be** initialized **to** (or **with**) a default value.

You need the preposition **with** or **to** in both the "must" version and your original. If you are talking about computer code, it's customary to say **initialized to**; in other contexts, **initialized with** may be more appropriate.

Comment: It's worth noting that a preposition should be used in the O.P.'s first sentence, too: _Criteria are initialized **with** a default value_.